# TypeScript complaining when trying to use a function as .replace argument

Tags: typescript

I have an array of objects for a `replace` function, which is inside a `forEach` loop (I did this so I wouldn't have to write `.replace` again and again). The `replacement` can either be a string or a function:

```
const content = `'Example'
"Another example

"Another example"`

const regexes = [{
  }, {
    name: 'apostrophe',
    pattern: /(?<=\w)\'(?=\w)|(?<=\w)\'(?!\w)/g,
    replacement: '&rsquo;'
  }, {
    name: 'doubleQuotes',
    pattern: /"([^"\n\r]*)("|$)/gm,
    replacement: (x: any,y: any,z: any) =>  z === '"' ? `&ldquo;${y}&rdquo;` : `&ldquo;${y}`
}]

regexes.forEach(regex => {
  content = content.replace(regex.pattern, regex.replacement)
})
```

TypeScript (inside VS Code) is throwing this type error:

[image]

> Argument of type 'string | ((x: any, y: any, z: any) => string)' is
> not assignable to parameter of type '(substring: string, ...args:
> any[]) => string'.
>
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '(substring: string, ...args:
> any[]) => string'.ts(2769)

I think TypeScript is complaining that one of the `replacement` is a function?

What should I change in the code to remove this type error?

[Here's there live code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAxg9gdmECIF4IAMDkBRAHgQwFsAHUTAKACIBBOGMACxACcIQCTRyrb6nX2RUiErpusOAGdIzEAHN2ISaggBtAN7kI2iHCIgAXBEz5iMacxjEmmADRadxfGETM4RgPQAKAPwAeFAAdAHcASkDMXyCwgB9fAJDwyJ8AQkSPOXsdCFlSfCgQQiQwI0wAMmZJAEcAVxgAbgptAF9bCE1svSLSgBMYGoAjUABFOsRJOwdtJxcWdwgPSi9VAD1KQLhA5gBdACpQr0oYgBJQjMIsnVzgfMLioy9cI3w4AE9bV%20e32wAvL9fQqgAHzaH6oFBoTCUTAQHwYMrAHq1BrHdSvZoVJF1eroCBGdAIrEotHNMTNbbcWQKXBKAB0ADMYMxsPkGF4qexge0HBJEMg0LzirTrrd2fJ2LSZq44G0ObhhSA8gUighQuRmqEgA) (I fixed the issues raised by the answer below.)

Comment: Share all the relevant code at https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, remove the empty entry from `regexes` or handle the empty entry in the `forEach`.  you also need to define `content` with a `let` instead of `const`, since you're modifying the value.

for the apostrophe replacement, try using `() => '&rsquo;'` instead of just a string.  that will align the types of your `replacement` field, making them all functions and the compiler will be happy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm curious, is there a way of making this work without making the first replacement a function?